# Mixing two different GPUs on the same mining rig

Tags: mining, gpu

Is it possible to mix 3 ASUS RX480, 1 AMD 7990 and 2 r9 380 in the same mining rig? If so, will it be possible to overclock them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/13949/can-i-mix-graphics-cards-on-a-mining-rig-rx480-and-rx-470

Comment: well how about if its a NVIDIA 750 and a RX 580?

Answer (score 1):

Different GPU can be used in a single mining rig . The issues that may possibly arise are:

1. Dynamic Hash Rate
2. Temperature fluctuations, since you are using different GPUs each may have different optimum temperatures.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there should be no major issues with that, especially since it is all AMD.